# CPNTools how to create the Concept Graph

Tags: cpn-tools

I have a concept for my Graphic, but i dont know how to rialize in CPNTools.
The Arrowy are the conections between the Place and Transition.

the conections:
arc: **Input** to **InitializeInput,**
from **InitializeInput** to **Chunks,**
from **Chunks** to **ComputePrimeTwins,**
from **Chunks** to **DistributeChunks,**
from **ComputePrimeTwins** to **Results,**
from **Results** to **CollectResults**

```
colset NUM = int;
colset CHUNK = list NUM;
colset RESULT = int;

val num_start = 2;
val num_end = 1024; 
val NP = 4;

fun chunk_size(num_start, num_end, NP) = (num_end - num_start + 1) div NP;
fun remainder(num_start, num_end, NP) = (num_end - num_start + 1) mod NP;

place: 
Input([num_start, num_end]) : NUM;
Chunks([]) : CHUNK;
Results([]) : RESULT;

transition: 
InitializeInput() =
  gardient:
    Input([start, end]) = num_start
    ==> Input([start + chunk_size(num_start, num_end, NP), end]);

DistributeChunks() =
gardient:  
    Input([start, end]) = num_start + chunk_size(num_start, num_end, NP)
    ==> Chunks(divide_range(start, end));

transition ComputePrimeTwins(chunk) =
gardient:  
  Chunks([chunk | _])
  ==> Results(compute_prime_twins(chunk));

transition CollectResults() =
  Results(counts)
  ==> print("Total prime twins found: " + sum(counts));
```